# iOS App to record narration with images

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an iPad app that can record a narrated audio track and edit it include still images to go with the spoken audio. The end product I'm looking for is a movie with a spoken audio track with still images placed at various points in the spoken track.

Can anyone recommend an iOS app that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [iMovie for iOS](http://www.apple.com/ios/imovie/)

iMovie for iOS will let you record sound using the voiceover tool and overlay this on media in your timeline, such as pictures imported from your camera roll, Photo Stream or imported pictures.

> Add background music, sound effects, and voiceover narration to your movie. And with new advanced audio tools, you can trim, split, duplicate, and reposition audio anywhere in the timeline.

[image: Voiceover Tool]

Comment: Awesome. So iMovie it is. Great to know a stock Apple app can do it.